# Copy cell images from Smartsheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, smartsheet-api

I am trying to make a copy of smart sheet data on my local disk. I am able to copy all the smart sheet data except for the cell images. Below is the code am using. This code works perfectly fine to copy the data but not the cell images
NOTE: I am not trying to copy the attachments from smart sheets; only the cell the images and data.
Could someone help me to enhance this code to copy the cell images as well?

```
import json
import os
import requests
import time


token = "Bearer <TOken>"


backed_up_sheets = {"Attach": 86960044478894,"test2":6659760455684}

dir = r'C:\Users\\me\SmartSheetsBackup\WorkSheet' + time.strftime("-%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M")

API_URL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/"

payload = {"Authorization": token,
           "Accept": "application/vnd.ms-excel,image/*"}


amount = len(backed_up_sheets)

i = 1
for el in backed_up_sheets:
    r = requests.get(API_URL + str(backed_up_sheets[el]) , headers=payload)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print ('Some problem with connections please retry later0')
        pass
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
       os.makedirs(dir)

    with open(dir + el + time.strftime("-%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M") +  ".xlsx", 'wb') as output:
        output.write(r.content)
    print ('Progress in sheets: ' + str(i) + '/' + str(amount))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Downloading a cell image is a (fairly tedious) multi-step process, as described here:  http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#download-cell-image.

Comment: Thank u for the link Kim. But there is no sample code or example to download cell image using Python. Can you help with any sample code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that the [Python SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk) doesn't yet contain functionality for working with Cell Images. i.e., that's why there's no sample code in the docs -- their SDK doesn't yet support that functionality. If that's the case, then you could fork the SDK repo & add that functionality yourself (and submit a PR back to the SDK repo for the future benefit of others) -- or you could simply add the basic HTTP request logic (to your code) for getting cell images, based on the API docs that I linked to previously.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete code sample:

```
# Download an image in a cell
def download_cell_image(client, sheet_id, row_id, column_id, default_filename):
    # Get desired row
    row = client.Sheets.get_row(sheet_id, row_id)
    cell = row.get_column(column_id)
    image = cell.image

    filename = getattr(image, 'alt_text', default_filename)

    # Obtain a temporary image URL
    imageUrl = ss_client.models.ImageUrl( { "imageId": image.id } ) 
    response = ss_client.Images.get_image_urls([imageUrl])
    url = response.image_urls[0].url

   # Download the image
    import requests
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Note that this requires SDK version 1.3.0 or later

Answer (score 0):

The same steps illustrated in the cURL example should work in Python. (Apologies that we don't have an complete published sample)

1. Get the image id from the cell object, as returned from [get_sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet)
2. Convert the image id to a download url, using `images.get_image_urls` ([docs](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-python-sdk/smartsheet.html#module-smartsheet.images))
3. Download the image from the url, probably using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library.